# CSS for each page in R Shiny

Tags: html, css, r, user-interface, shiny

I've written an R shiny application and am styling it before I complete it. I've written a small amount of HTML and want to change things such as the background colour using CSS.
After consulting online I found I needed to seperate my css using the class argument, however when I specify a class for each page, it brings back no CSS at all.

Below is a shortened version of my R shiny application. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
library(shiny)

setwd("C:\\Users\\FRSAWG\\Desktop\\Application\\Shiny")

user <- shinyUI(navbarPage("",

tabPanel("Home Page",
       div(class="one",
         div(tags$style("#one body{background-color:blue;color:white;font-family:Arial}"),
            div(HTML("<h1><b><center>Home Page</center></b></h1>"))))),
tabPanel("Glossary",
       div(class="two",
           div(tags$style("#two body{background-color:red;color:white;font-family:Arial}"),
               div(HTML("<h1><b><center>Glossary</center></b></h1>")))))
))

serv <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {})

shinyApp(user, serv)
```

For reference I've designated **one** and **two** the class names for each of the pages.

Comment: Check out my updated answer - got rid of the flickering that was sometimes appearing in my previous suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE:** Using the package `shinyjs` by Dean Attali ([link](http://deanattali.com/2015/04/23/shinyjs-r-package/)), I wrote a helper function that you can call from R to create and run a jQuery function to modify the CSS element of a given object (or selector, in general) based on input from R syntax. You can use this to modify the CSS for your `<body>` when the tab changes.

This solves the problem with my previous suggestion - now there's no need to toggle the class of the body, which was sometimes causing flickering when for a split second all of the style classes for `<body>` were toggled off.

Here's the working example:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

## Modify the CSS style of a given selector
modifyStyle <- function(selector, ...) {

  values <- as.list(substitute(list(...)))[-1L]
  parameters <- names(values)

  args <- Map(function(p, v) paste0("'", p,"': '", v,"'"), parameters, values)
  jsc <- paste0("$('",selector,"').css({", paste(args, collapse = ", "),"});")

  shinyjs::runjs(code = jsc)

}

# UI for the app
user <- shinyUI(
  navbarPage(title = "", id = "navtab",
             header = div(useShinyjs()),
             tabPanel("Home Page",
                      div(HTML("<h1><b><center>Home Page</center></b></h1>")),
                      "More text."
             ),

             tabPanel("Glossary",
                      div(HTML("<h1><b><center>Glossary</center></b></h1>")),
                      "More text."
             )
  )
)

# Server for the app
serv <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  observeEvent(input$navtab, {
    currentTab <- input$navtab # Name of the current tab

    if (currentTab == "Home Page") {
      modifyStyle("body", background = "blue", color = "white", 'font-family' = "Arial")
    }
    if (currentTab == "Glossary")  {
      modifyStyle("body", background = "red", color = "white", 'font-family' = "Arial")
    }
  })

})

shinyApp(user, serv)
```

---

I'm new to CSS myself, but it seems your problem can be fixed by just altering the CSS tags slightly. Changing the `#one` to `.one` and removing the `body` preceding the brackets will make the CSS style get applied to the divs of class `one`.

Using the selector `#one` would be changing the CSS style of a div whose *id*, not class, is `one`. Here's a link to [a guide on w3shools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_selectors.asp) explaining the use of different selectors in CSS syntax.

Some other notes:

- You could also use a `tags$head` to organize your style tags in
  one place, instead of spreading them around the code. (This is down to personal preference, though.)
- You can pass a `class` argument to `tabPanel` to set its CSS class - this removes the need for the inner div to set the class.

Modified example code:

```
library(shiny)

user <- shinyUI(navbarPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML(".one {background-color: blue; color: white; font-family: Arial}")),
    tags$style(HTML(".two {background-color: red;  color: white; font-family: Arial}"))
  ),

  tabPanel("Home Page", class = "one",
      div(HTML("<h1><b><center>Home Page</center></b></h1>")),
      "More text."
  ),

  tabPanel("Glossary", class = "two",
      div(HTML("<h1><b><center>Glossary</center></b></h1>")),
      "More text."
  )
))

serv <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {})

shinyApp(user, serv)
```

Like I mentioned, I'm new to CSS, so I'm not 100% sure if this is the output you are looking for, though.

**EDIT2:** Here's a solution using the package `shinyjs` to update the class of the `<body>` when the selected tab changes. (Note that in order to use the functions from `shinyjs`, you need to include `useShinyjs()` in  your ui.)

The idea is to make `navbarPage` return the name of the tab that's currently active in `input$navtab` by setting its id to `navtab`. Then we can use the `toggleClass` function from the package `shinyjs` to change the class of the `<body>` dynamically, and thus have the appropriate CSS styling applied.

It's not perfect, since the class change only happens after the server gets notified that the tab has changed, which sometimes causes the background to flash before changing. It can get a bit annoying. I suspect a better solution would be to use javascript to change the `<body>` class when clicking the link to change the tab, but I couldn't figure out how to do that with Shiny.

Here's the code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

user <- shinyUI(
  navbarPage(title = "", id = "navtab",
  header = tags$head(
    useShinyjs(),
    tags$style(HTML(".one {background: blue; color: white; font-family: Arial}")),
    tags$style(HTML(".two {background: red;  color: white; font-family: Arial}"))
  ),

    tabPanel("Home Page",
      div(HTML("<h1><b><center>Home Page</center></b></h1>")),
      "More text."
    ),

    tabPanel("Glossary",
     div(HTML("<h1><b><center>Glossary</center></b></h1>")),
     "More text."
    )
  )
)

serv <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

   observeEvent(input$navtab, {
     shinyjs::toggleClass(selector = "body", class = "one",
                 condition = (input$navtab == "Home Page"))

     shinyjs::toggleClass(selector = "body", class = "two",
                 condition = (input$navtab == "Glossary"))
   })

})

shinyApp(user, serv)
```

Comment: This solves my problem of specifying which 'page' receives which colour, however running this script means that just the text background changes to blue or red, I was hoping to have the whole background blue on one page and red on the other (hence the body argument).

Comment: I thought you might have, that's what I was trying to address in the second code snippet I edited in. Seems I made a copy-paste error somewhere though - I'm sure it was working yesterday but doesn't seem to work now (as in, changing tabs would change the colour of everything but the navigation bar).

Comment: @Andrew I added an updated solution using javascript functionality included in the `shinyjs` package. It's not perfect, but it'll change the whole background.

Comment: Just a comment about using shinyjs: your solution using `runjs` is very nice and clever, but I wanted to point out that in the future it might be easier to create an actual javascript function and call it directly -- look into `shinyjs::extendShinyjs`.  Thanks for educating people about it @MikkoM!

Comment: Good point - that would probably be a more elegant solution. I actually looked into using `extendShinyjs` before coming up with this, but I have to admit I was slightly intimidated by the passing of arguments between R and JS - I've only just started learning jQuery, so I'm not too comfortable with coding in JS yet. PS. Great job with the `shinyjs` package @daattali! I've found it really helpful and inspiring - using it was actually what made me want to learn JavaScript myself.